# NSURLCache Alamofire removing cached responses

Tags: ios, swift, caching, alamofire, nsurlcache

I'm using the following code to test a behavior in `NSURLCache`. I initialize an `API` instance in `AppDelegate`. I configure the manager according to Alamofire's documentation, I configure the shared cache, and I assign `dataTaskWillCacheResponse` to make sure that the response will indeed be cached.

Then I call `makeRequest` which checks if a cached response exists (which it shouldn't on the first launch) and then I use my `manager` to make a request using the same URL so that the request is equivalent throughout the test.

My breakpoint at `dataTaskWillCacheResponse` is hit, I continue, the `responseJSON` block is executed and is `Success`ful so I `performTests` using the request.

1. First, I check if the response is cached. **It is: good!**
2. Second, **(and this is the problem)** I remove the cached response for that request and then check if it exists. **It does: bad!**
3. Third, I check if removing *all* cached responses will remove that response. **It does: good! *But it's odd that that worked and the previous attempt at just removing the single response didn't...***

#### Here's the code:

```
import Alamofire

class API: Manager.SessionDelegate {
    
    var manager: Manager!

    override init() {
        super.init()
        manager = Manager(session: urlSession(), delegate: self)
        configureCache(memoryCapacityMB: 5, diskCapacityMB: 25)
        manager.delegate.dataTaskWillCacheResponse = { urlSession, dataTask, cachedResponse in
            // Placing a breakpoint here confirms that the response is going to be cached
            return cachedResponse
        }
    }
    
    private func urlSession() -> NSURLSession {
        let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        return NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    }
    
    private func configureCache(memoryCapacityMB memory: Int, diskCapacityMB disk: Int) {
        let memoryCapacity = memory * 1024 * 1024
        let diskCapacity = disk * 1024 * 1024
        let sharedCache = NSURLCache(memoryCapacity: memoryCapacity, diskCapacity: diskCapacity, diskPath: nil)
        NSURLCache.setSharedURLCache(sharedCache)
    }
    
    // MARK: Request
    
    func makeRequest() {
        // The response should be nil on the first launch since nothing has been cached
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")!)
        let response = NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().cachedResponseForRequest(request)
        print(response)
        
        manager.request(.GET, request.URLString).responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .Success:
                self.performTests(with: response.request!)
    
            case .Failure:
                break
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    func performTests(with request: NSURLRequest) {
        // Should exist
        var response = NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().cachedResponseForRequest(request)
        print(response)
        // And it does: good!
        
        // Remove the cached resopnse and check if it exists
        NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().removeCachedResponseForRequest(request)
        response = NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().cachedResponseForRequest(request)
        print(response)
        // And it does: bad!
        
        // Try removing all cached responses and check if it exists
        NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().removeAllCachedResponses()
        response = NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().cachedResponseForRequest(request)
        print(response)
        // And it doesn't: good! But odd...
    }
    
}
```

**So how *does* one remove the cached response of a single request then?** And is this unintended behavior? Or is `NSURLCache` behaving correctly and I'm just missing something? Thanks ahead of time for taking a look!

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, have you found a solution?

Comment: @Louis, I haven't tested with iOS 11 or Swift 4, but from what I recall, the default behavior in iOS 10 was indeed incorrect and so I had to write a custom cache. I don't have the code for that cache any longer as it was for an enterprise app.

Answer (score 0):

My recollection is that most URL cache changes are not synchronous.  They only actually happen after you return to the run loop and allow various asynchronous callbacks to occur.

Try running the rest of the code asynchronously after a delay of 3-5 seconds and see if the request has been removed.

If that doesn't fix the problem, file a bug.